# combine results of 2 rows with start on row1 and end on row2

Tags: mariadb

I have this on a MariaDB version 5.5.65

```
datetimeconnect datetimeend queue   agent   event
02/05/2022 10:02:31 02/05/2022 10:02:31 "5009"  "Mikey Blogs"   "ADDMEMBER"
02/05/2022 15:53:58 02/05/2022 15:53:58 "5009"  "Mikey Blogs"   "REMOVEMEMBER"
02/05/2022 16:42:28 02/05/2022 16:42:28 "5005"  "Mikey Blogs"   "ADDMEMBER"
02/05/2022 18:02:45 02/05/2022 18:02:45 "5005"  "Mikey Blogs"   "REMOVEMEMBER"
03/05/2022 10:01:33 03/05/2022 10:01:33 "5009"  "Mikey Blogs"   "ADDMEMBER"
03/05/2022 16:01:22 03/05/2022 16:01:22 "5009"  "Mikey Blogs"   "REMOVEMEMBER"
```

the first row with 'ADDMEMBER' is the start and the second 'REMOVEMEMBER' is the end..
so I need to show, on each row: Start (row1) end(row2), queue, name, and datediff (end, start) to show the duration..

I admin I never had to combine rows before..
If anyone could assist, I greatly appreciate.
Have a nice day

Addition:
Tge output I would like to see is (one a single row): start date (row1) ADDMEMBER, end date (row 2) REMOVEMEMBER,  diference in hh:mm:ss, name, queue number.   and show create table result:

```
CREATE TABLE `queue_stats_mv` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '1971-01-01 00:00:00',
    `datetimeconnect` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `datetimeend` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `queue` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `agent` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `event` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `uniqueid` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `real_uniqueid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `clid` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `url` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `did` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `position` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `info1` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `info2` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `info3` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `info4` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `info5` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `overflow` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `combined_waittime` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `waittime` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `talktime` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ringtime` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `fecha` (`datetime`),
    KEY `ev` (`event`),
    KEY `pidx` (`real_uniqueid`,`id`),
    KEY `uni` (`uniqueid`),
    KEY `runi` (`real_uniqueid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1209991 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: what timezone are the times?

Comment: could you show the desired output for your sample data?

Comment: for example: 02/05/2022 (date start) | 10:02:31 (Start time) | 02/05/2022 (date end)| 10:53:58 (time end) | sec_to_time(datediff(row2 datetimeend,row1 datetimeconnect) as "duration" |5009 | Mikey Blogs

Comment: and the time zone are EST

Comment: in other words I need the 'Add member' and the 'remove member' rows into 1 so I can do a datediff and calculate the duration in that queue.

Comment: anyone please?  Appreciate if anyone could please

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: do you want to ignore mismatched add/removes (remove before the first add, add after the last remove, add following an add, remove following a remove)?  if not, how would they be shown?

Comment: is remove always on the same day as add?  if not, datediff is going to be incorrect when the time includes a daylight saving transition (assuming you meant EST/EDT, not just EST)

Comment: it would be helpful if you would edit your question to show output (as text, not an image) of `show create table yourtablename`

Comment: I actually pasted the results there, not an image. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: select
datetimeconnect,datetimeend,queue,agent,event
-- ,sec_to_time(datediff(datetimeconnect,datetimeend))
from
  queue_stats_mv 
    where cast(queue_stats_mv.datetime as date) >'2022-04-30' 
  and queue_stats_mv.event IN ('ADDMEMBER','REMOVEMEMBER')
  and agent like 'Mikey Bloggs'
order by
  queue_stats_mv.datetime

Comment: 1 row is the start and the other row is the end..  I'm trying to see start, end, duration in one row

Comment: that part was clear.  can you please answer my questions?  and don't paste output into comments, please do edit your question with it.

Comment: Just did and hope is clear. I'm sorry if I'm mistaking.  Hope there's a simple solution to this. Abd thank you for your time

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: oh I'm sorry: 5.5.65-MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

On newer versions of mariadb (10.2 or higher) you would use lag or lead window functions in a subquery for this, which will likely be quite a bit more efficient.  In your very old version, the easiest way is to do a self join to find the following event (joining *all* following events, but using where conditions to ensure a removemember is found and that it is in fact the immediately following event):

```
select addmember.queue, addmember.agent, addmember.datetimeconnect, removemember.datetimeconnect
from queue_stats_mv addmember
join queue_stats_mv removemember on
    removemember.queue=addmember.queue and
    removemember.agent=addmember.agent and
    removemember.event in ('ADDMEMBER','REMOVEMEMBER') and
    removemember.datetimeconnect > addmember.datetimeconnect
where
    addmember.event='ADDMEMBER' and
    removemember.event='REMOVEMEMBER' and
    not exists (
        select 1
        from queue_stats_mv inbetween
        where
            inbetween.queue=addmember.queue and
            inbetween.agent=addmember.agent and
            inbetween.event in ('ADDMEMBER','REMOVEMEMBER') and
            inbetween.datetimeconnect between addmember.datetimeconnect and removemember.datetimeconnect
    )
```

You will need a composite index on `(queue,agent,event,datetimeconnect)` (or some variation of order as long as the time is last), though event only needs to be included if there are lots of other events than the addmember and removemember.

If there is some maximum duration expected, you can improve the query by adding that to the join on clause, e.g.:

```
and removemember.datetimeconnect <= addmember.datetimeconnect + interval 1 day
```

I am assuming you never have multiple events for the same queue/agent with the same datetimeconnect; that is possible to make work, but would require you to show your schema.

A more efficient way would be to emulate the lag window function using variables, but that's only worth doing if the easy way is not efficient enough.

Since you have non-UTC times, datediff will not calculate the duration correctly in all cases, but that is better off being addressed in a separate question.

Comment: updated; forgot to restrict the events in the not exists subquery

Comment: thank you. I set it to run for one day only but it is still running ...  an egent can log on the same number of queues at one time.. so under queue you might see (5009,5001,5008) for example.. the DB is the FreePBX  from Sangoma if it helps.. still running and no much happening :/

Comment: did you see the comment about "You will need a composite index ..."?  I really meant it.  Please edit your question and add the output of `show create table queue_stats_mv`

Comment: but can you have events for the same agent and queue at the same time?

Comment: same queue same agent same time is not going to happen. Question edited.

Comment: so you need to do `alter table queue_stats_mv add index event_queue_agent_time (event,queue,agent,datetimeconnect);`.  if it still doesn't perform well, please edit your question to show the exact query you are using, and the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT restofthequery`

Comment: thank you ysth -  this is beyond me though and I will have to spend more time on it. THank you for your kind assistance